# In cucumber @AfterStep do not executing on version: 5.7.0

Tags: cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I'm working with the cucumber, testng project and integrated the latest cucumber into that.
If I use TestNg annotations in my runner class they will execute fine. But if I use cucumber annotations in my runner class it will not execute.
So I'm confusing why and looking for a reason for that.

Below code block 'tearDown' method does not execute after I execute the 'TestCases' class.
feature file executes without any issue till the end but the '@AfterStep' method does not execute.
**Any issue in my dependencies or?**

**Since I use cucumber 5.7.0 with testng '@AfterStep' is import under

'import io.cucumber.java.AfterStep;'**

```html
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.java.AfterStep;

public class TestCases extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {


@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
                "json:target/cucumber-report.json"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/featureFiles/",},
        glue = {"com.tests.testSteps"},
        tags = {"@regressiontest"})

     @AfterStep
        public void tearDown() {
            System.out.println("========= This line not executing ===========");
       
        }
}
```

```
POM file configuration as below:
```

```html
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should put @AfterStep in step definitions . I tested it with `cucumber-java` 6.9.1 and it works fine . However, I am using it with `junit` . My `pom` looks like this

```
<junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
<cucumber.version>6.9.1</cucumber.version>
...
...
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make your runner file different than step definition. This is my runner file

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
  (
       plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "json:target/AcceptanceTestResults.json"
        },
        features = "src/test/resources/com/test/RestAssured.feature",          
         glue = {"com.test.stepdefs"}
                    
)
public class AcceptanceIT {
}
```

And then put your step defs in a diff class

```
public class RestAssuredIT { 

 ....
 ....
@AfterStep // this imports from  io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.9.1
    public void afterEveryStep(){

        //this prints after each step in feature file
        System.out.println("***after every step****");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I tried out in the method on step definition as you said using TestNg (with my existing pom configs), and works fine and will continue on that approach.